# Allow only numbers and underscore(_) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I need to have a valid input like this `122_123`. If the entered id is wrong I need to display an error message. This has to be done using jQuery. I have the below code which doesn't seem to work for some reason.

```
$('[id*=search]').unbind().click(function() {
    var numPattern = /^[0-9_]+$/;
    //check if the copy pasted value of RequestId has alphabets.
    if (!(/^[_0-9]*$/i).test($('[id*=reqId]').val()){
        alert('Invalid');
        $('[id*=reqId]').val('');
        return false;
    }
    displaySpinner();
    return true;
});
```

What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: what is the error you get/wrong result you get?

Comment: Please can you post relevant fragment of your HTML too

Comment: `/^[_0-9]*$/i` i guess you want to use `g` flag instead of `i`: : :`/^[_0-9]*$/g` or both but i guess in your case `i` is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you this may help you :--

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $('#input_id').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    console.log($('#input_id').val());
    if ((/[_0-9]$/i).test($('#input_id').val())) {
      $('p').html("true");
    } else {
      $('p').html("false");
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="input_id" type="text" />
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

What i think you are actually checking for opposite of `.test()`. You should remove the `!` not sign from the condition:

```
if ((/^[_0-9]*$/i).test($('[id*=reqId]').val()){
```